# tf.self_adjoint_eig fails for covariance matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I use tf.self_adjoint_eig to get an eigendecomposition of a covariance matrix, I get "Self Adjoint Eigen decomposition wasnot [sic] successful. The input might not be valid."

Say I'm whitening data (and it is a tensorflow element so I will not fall back to numpy's svd), then the error crops up when I use this code:

```
def whiten(x):
    x -= tf.reduce_mean(x, reduction_indices=[0])
    decomp = tf.stop_gradient(tf.self_adjoint_eig(tf.matmul(x, x, transpose_a=True)/n))
    evals = decomp[0, :]
    evecs = decomp[1:, :]
    xrot_scaled = tf.matmul(x, evecs)/(tf.sqrt(evals) + 1e-5)
    return tf.matmul(xrot_scaled, evecs, transpose_b=True)
```

It is to my understanding that the input to tf.self_adjoint_eig is psd, so the solver should have no validity concerns. Ideas?